# add column for calculation in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I need to create a new column in the screen view to calculate the final total of the products that I have entered in the system.

I thought it was done with separator but it doesn't work, how can I add that column in tree?

Comment: A bit more info, like code, would really help, wouldn't it?

Comment: for example I want to do something like this, where the final total goes down https://ibb.co/ZXPXz7m  
Is there any code that allows you to do that and what would it be?